# How to start picture in picture mode instead of going to background? Like youtube premium

Tags: android-lifecycle, onpause, background-mode, android-picture-in-picture

I know how to enable picture-in-picture mode itself when an app runs normally but the problem is that I want to activate it when the app goes to background mode i.e. on activity pause.
A good example of such behavior is YouTube premium app on android. When a video is playing and a user taps "home" button the video just keeps on playing in PIP mode.
I tried to implement LifecycleObserver and launch picture-in-picture mode from its "onPause" callback. But it says "activity must be resumed to enter picture-in-picture".
I took a look inside onPause method and it's implemented in a way that super.onPause() must be called first, so I can't just override it and not to call "super".

Does anyone have any suggestion on how implement this Youtube-like behavior?
p.s. I've googled a lot before asking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs provide an example for this:

```java
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint () {
    if (iWantToBeInPipModeNow()) {
        enterPictureInPictureMode();
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture#pip_button

Comment: The docs are terrible. onUserLeaveHint can be called at other times as well, so you could be incorrectly attempting to enter pip when the app is not backgrounded.